# Pygame - Flappy Bird from Clear Code - How do I save the high score for the next time I open the game and display it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been learning Pygame for 3 days. Now I want to save and load the high score and display it.

This has been a very difficult task to achieve in other engines I've used - saving and loading, that is - but with sheer determination, I have managed to do it on one of my main engines.

Any help will do.

The code:

```
import pygame, sys, random

def draw_floor():
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos,900))
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos + 576,900))

def create_pipe():
    random_pipe_pos = random.choice(pipe_height)
    bottom_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midtop = (584,random_pipe_pos))
    top_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midbottom = (584,random_pipe_pos -300))
    return bottom_pipe,top_pipe

def move_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.centerx -= 5
    visible_pipes = [pipe for pipe in pipes if pipe.right > -50]
    return visible_pipes

def draw_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.bottom >= 1024:
            screen.blit(pipe_surface,pipe)
        else:
            flip_pipe = pygame.transform.flip(pipe_surface,False,True)
            screen.blit(flip_pipe,pipe)

def check_collision(pipes):
    global can_score
    
    for pipe in pipes:
        if bird_rect.colliderect(pipe):
            hit_sound.play()
            can_score = True
            return False

        if bird_rect.top <= -100 or bird_rect.bottom >= 900:
            can_score = True
            hit_sound.play()
            return False

    return True

def rotate_bird(bird):
    new_bird = pygame.transform.rotozoom(bird,-bird_movement * 3,1)
    return new_bird

def bird_animation():
    new_bird = bird_frames[bird_index]
    new_bird_rect = new_bird.get_rect(center = (100,bird_rect.centery))
    return new_bird,new_bird_rect

def score_display(game_state):
    if game_state == 'main_game':
        score_surface = game_font.render(str(int(score)),True,(255,255,255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,100))
        screen.blit(score_surface,score_rect)
    if game_state == 'game_over':
        score_surface = game_font.render(f'Score: {int(score)}',True,(255,255,255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,100))
        screen.blit(score_surface,score_rect)

        high_score_surface = game_font.render(f'High score: {int(high_score)}',True,(255,255,255))
        high_score_rect = high_score_surface.get_rect(center = (288,850))
        screen.blit(high_score_surface,high_score_rect)

def update_score(score,high_score):
    if score > high_score:
        high_score = score
    return high_score

def pipe_score_check():
    global score, can_score
    
    if pipe_list:
        for pipe in pipe_list:
            if 95 < pipe.centerx < 105 and can_score:
                score += 1
                point_sound.play()
                can_score = False
                if pipe.centerx < 0:
                    can_score = True
                    
# pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency = 44100, size = 16, channels = 1, buffer = 512)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576,1024))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_font = pygame.font.Font('04B_19.ttf',40)

# Variables
gravity = 0.25
bird_movement = 0
game_active = True
score = 0
high_score = 0
can_score = True
# Loading images

bg_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/background-day.png').convert()
bg_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bg_surface)

floor_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/base.png').convert()
floor_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(floor_surface)
floor_x_pos = 0

bird_downflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-downflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_midflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-midflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_upflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-upflap.png').convert_alpha())
bird_frames = [bird_downflap,bird_midflap,bird_upflap]
bird_index = 0
bird_surface = bird_frames[bird_index]
bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))

BIRDFLAP = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(BIRDFLAP,200)

# bird_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/yellowbird-midflap.png').convert_alpha()
# bird_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bird_surface)
# bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))

pipe_surface = pygame.image.load('assets/pipe-green.png').convert()
pipe_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pipe_surface)

pipe_list = []

SPAWNPIPE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,1500)
pipe_height = [400,600,800]

game_over_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('assets/message.png').convert_alpha())
game_over_rect = game_over_surface.get_rect(center = (288,512))

flap_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_wing.wav')
hit_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_hit.wav')
point_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/sfx_point.wav')
countdown_sound_score = 100

# Event loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and game_active:
                bird_movement = 0
                bird_movement -= 12
                flap_sound.play()
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and game_active == False:
                game_active = True
                pipe_list.clear()
                bird_rect.center = (100,512)
                bird_movement = 0
                score = 0
                
        if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:
            pipe_list.extend(create_pipe())

        if event.type == BIRDFLAP:
            if bird_index < 2:
                bird_index += 1
            else:
                bird_index = 0

            bird_surface,bird_rect = bird_animation()

# Pasting background image
    screen.blit(bg_surface,(0,0))
    
    if game_active:
# Bird movement and pasting bird
        bird_movement += gravity
        rotated_bird = rotate_bird(bird_surface)
        bird_rect.centery += bird_movement
        screen.blit(rotated_bird,bird_rect)
        game_active = check_collision(pipe_list)

# Pipes
        pipe_list = move_pipes(pipe_list)
        draw_pipes(pipe_list)
# Score
        pipe_score_check()
        score_display('main_game')
    else:   
        screen.blit(game_over_surface,game_over_rect)
        high_score = update_score(score,high_score)
        score_display('game_over')
                      
# Floor movement and pasting floor image
    floor_x_pos -= 1
    draw_floor()
    if floor_x_pos <=-576:
        floor_x_pos = 0
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

This will help me greatly.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Have you looked into reading and writing from files? That's how you'll be able to save and retrieve data between running the program. Perhaps have a file `highscore.txt` which you read when you start the program, and update whenever the user gets a new high score?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have a file with your score. You will write the score to it before closing the game, or whenever you want to save the score. and read the score when you open the game.

Here is an example of the read and write functions to achive this:

```
def write_score(score):
    with open("highscore.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(score))

def read_score():
    with open("highscore.txt", 'r') as file:
        return int(file.read())
```

(Haven't tested the code but I'm pretty sure that this will work, if not, I can fix it)

Comment: This will work fine, though it's often very convenient to use the `json` library, which can directly read and write a dictionary of strings to a file handle with `json.load()` and `json.dump()` (`.dumps()` and `.loads()` for strings respectively, which can be easier to reason about) https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: This would (for example) allow the user to easily read and write a collect of names and their scores to a file.

Comment: Yeah, I guess json would be better for this.